# How to set keep alive in ingress rule for nginx inress controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I need to set keep-alive to 0 for an application and would like to do it on ingressrule layer. Is that possible?

Is there any annotation for that?

Answer (score 2):

In `mandatory.yaml`, you can add

`data: keep-alive-requests: "1000000"`

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
data:
  proxy-connect-timeout: "10s"
  proxy-read-timeout: "10s"
  client-max-body-size: "2m"
  keep-alive-requests: "1000000"
  upstream-keepalive-requests: "1000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible for Nginx Ingress Controller.

But you need to use a ConfigMap for this, not an annotation.

> **keep-alive**
>
> Sets the time during which a keep-alive client connection will stay open on the server side. The zero value disables keep-alive client connections.
>
> References: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_timeout

Here is the example:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  keep-alive: 0
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
```

For more information, visit the following links:
[Nginx Ingress ConfigMaps](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap.md) and [keep-alive](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap.md#keep-alive)